# Manually accept tcp clients

Tags: sockets, client, tcpclient, tcplistener

Is there a way in which I can chose the clients that my `TcpListener` accepts? Or to set my `TcpListener` to accept connection only from a specific IP?

C#, .NET 4.0

Comment: What language/framework does your `TcpListener` come from? There are many `TcpListener`s in the world.

Comment: After you've accepted a TCP connection, use getpeername() (or TcpListener's equivalent to that) to find out the remote peer's IP address, and if you don't like the IP address, close the connection.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner, i do not want to accept and then close, i want to accept connection from only one ip wich i specify. Is this possible ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, at least not from a normal user-space program.  Firewalls can do that, but they use low-level (non-portable) hooks into the kernel to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Building IP address filters into application software is a Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup>. Do the filtering on the firewall and/or implement proper connection authentication.